# Is there a "touch slop" constant for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

On Android, there is a "touch slop" concept, representing the minimum distance "a touch can wander before we think the user is scrolling". Is there a similar concept / constant on iOS that we can use?

Reference for Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getScaledTouchSlop()

-- Edit with more information --

Here's my use case: I'm actually implementing a custom gesture recognizer for general UIView. It should fire touch down, touch up & click event when appropriate. The desired effect would be to simulate how UIControls respond to touch gestures on general UIViews. The problem is, when the UIView is inside a scrollview, the click event should not fire when the scrollview starts scrolling. So I'm merely seeking for a read-only access to the constant, or wondering if such a constant is commonly agreed.

Comment: Do you want a method to fire on a touch down event even if the `UIView` is within a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Yes. The effect is, if there's a button-like view in the scrollview, the background color should be darkened when touch down, and restored to normal when touch up. If the finger remains in the button-like view when the touch up happens, a click event is fired. If the scrollview starts scrolling because of the finger movement, the gesture recognizer is canceled, and a touch up event is immediately fired without firing click.

Answer (score 0):

A "touch slop" property only applies if you are using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer.` (Take a look at the [`allowableMovement` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILongPressGestureRecognizer/allowableMovement).) The system handles all the gesture classification logic for you behind the scenes. If you need this functionality for a normal `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, you should implement your own `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass. More information on subclassing can be found in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UIGestureRecognizer.).

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Here's my use case: I'm actually implementing a custom gesture recognizer for general UIView. It should fire touch down, touch up & click event when appropriate. The desired effect would be to simulate how UIControls respond to touch gestures on general UIViews. The problem is, when the UIView is inside a scrollview, the click event should not fire when the scrollview starts scrolling. So I'm merely seeking for a read-only access to the constant, or wondering if such a constant is commonly agreed.